# androidpublisher api google authorname empty

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have been testing the google api to get the comments of my android application in google play and it always returns me the empty authorname, do I need some other permission? I put the json of what returns me.

Thank you!

Comment: Which method in the API are you using exactly?  and which type of credentials are you using to access the api?

Comment: Hello dalmto, thanks for replying, I am using the credentials that are in console developer with the fingerprint of signing certificate, I get all the data except the authorname of the comment. And I'm using the C # library, latest version, I use this call await service.Reviews.List ("my.app"). ExecuteAsync () ;, where my clientid is the one I use in console developer and is linked to my account Android developer.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an issue with fields

```
var request = service.Reviews.List ("my.app");
request.Fields = "*";
var results = request.ExecuteAsync() ;
```

I don't have access to that api so the code is an educated guess give it a try let me know if it doesn't work.  Try testing it here as well [Google APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidpublisher/v2/androidpublisher.reviews.list).

Update 1:

I have one last guess try running a [Reviews.Get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/get) request after your review.list maybe the name isn't return in the list it should be though.

```
var request = service.Reviews.Get("my.app",reviewIdFromListRequest);
request.Fields = "*";
var results = request.ExecuteAsync() ;
```

If this doesn't work i say we log it as a bug.

Update 2:

apparently its a documented bug[image]

Found in this documentation page [reviews](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews#retrieving_a_set_of_reviews)

Comment: Thanks dalmto, I have tried and returns all data except the authorname. The scope I use is AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher, will I be missing some other permission?

"reviews": [
  {
   "reviewId": "gp:AOqpTOxxxx",
   "authorName": "",
   "comments": [
    {
     "userComment": {
      "text": "\tPues soy Mateo y quiero daros la opinión de que me lo acabo de bajar.",
      "lastModified": {
       "seconds": "1497598108",
       "nanos": 548000000
      },
      "starRating": 5,

Comment: probably not sounds like a bug to me. one last guess try running a https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/get after your review .list using the id returned from the list.

Comment: Check update it would be nice if they would define rare cases.

Comment: Yes, all the tests I have done with get as well. I get all the phone data, but the authorname always comes empty

Comment: I wonder if its a privacy issue.  I havent been able to find any where we can ask.